# What are the descriptions of the available creatures for Summon Warlock's Ally?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, warlock

The D&D Compendium lists a level 9 Warlock daily power called Summon Warlock's Ally which includes the following line of description:

```
You summon a creature associated with your pact in an unoccupied space within range.
```

But nowhere in the description is the description of what pacts get what allies, or what powers those allies have. Does anyone know where in the compendium that information is or what it is in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under [Hexblade](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=793) (Warlock) it notes:

> Binder's Ally (Gloom)
>
> You can use summon warlock’s ally to summon a [shadow lurk](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/associate.aspx?id=21).
>
> Binder's Ally (Star) You can use summon warlock’s ally to summon a
> [soul eater](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/associate.aspx?id=23).
>
> Summon Warlock's Ally (Fey) You can use summon warlock’s ally to
> summon a [wood woad guardian](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/associate.aspx?id=6).
>
> Summon Warlock's Ally (Gloom) You can use summon warlock's ally to
> summon a [dark creeper](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/associate.aspx?id=25).
>
> Summon Warlock's Ally (Infernal) You can use summon warlock’s ally to
> summon a [spined devil lackey](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/associate.aspx?id=8).
>
> Summon Warlock's Ally (Star) You can use summon warlock's ally to
> summon a [thought phantom](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/associate.aspx?id=10).
>
> Summon Warlock's Ally (White Well) If you have the sword of the White
> Well, you can use summon warlock’s ally to summon a [mourning
> handmaiden](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/associate.aspx?id=19).

These creatures are listed under the "companions and familiars" section, and are linked above.