# If a Warlock's Summoned Ally deals damage, does Curse damage apply too?

Tags: dnd-4e, warlock, summoning

I have a Warlock with a summoned creature from [Summon Warlock's Ally](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10287/what-are-the-descriptions-of-the-available-creatures-for-summon-warlocks-ally/10288#10288). A player with this summoned ally must use their standard action in order to control the ally. When the ally does damage to an enemy afflicted by your Warlock's Curse, does that enemy still take the extra damage from the Curse, even if you aren't the one dealing the damage yourself?

> ## Warlock's Curse
>
> Once per turn as a minor action, you can place a Warlock's Curse on the enemy nearest to you that you can see. A cursed enemy is more vulnerable to your attacks. If you damage a cursed enemy, you deal 1d6 per tier extra damage. You decide whether to apply the extra damage after making the damage roll. You can deal this extra damage once per round.

Comment: What book(s) are you referring to for Familiars?

Comment: This is what I found on familiars ( I am a Fey Pact), so that would make it my source.http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10287/what-are-the-descriptions-of-the-available-creatures-for-summon-warlocks-ally/10288#10288

Comment: @PurpleMonkey If you're considering changing a question completely, it's almost always going to be a better idea to just ask the question separately. You can always create a more canonical or general question on the topic, and self-answer it, if you like!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You are still making the attack.

> If a summoning power allows the summoned creature to attack, the **summoner makes an attack through the creature**, as specified in the power description ([RC 120-121](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=85))

When your summon makes an attack, you are attacking, and you are damaging. Thus if the target is cursed by you, you can apply curse damage to it.