# Do Warlock Ally's attack stats not level up?

Tags: dnd-4e, warlock, familiars

I notice that a Warlock's Summon basic attack is +5 vs Fortitude. (from the power Summon Warlock Ally)

(See here: [What are the descriptions of the available creatures for Summon Warlock's Ally?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10287/what-are-the-descriptions-of-the-available-creatures-for-summon-warlocks-ally/10288#10288))

While the description of the beast says it uses your defensive stats, it says nothing of attacks. Does that mean that there is no way to increase your pets chance to hit and it remains as +5? Seems like a rather weak pet if that is the case.

Comment: Just a heads up, use the power name in questions. This is not a familiar, it's a summon. Summons are always driven by a power, so use the power name when asking questions about it.

Answer (score 3):

Your ally gets X+your level to hit. Look at the [Satyr of the Night](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/associate.aspx?id=82)

> Attack: Melee 1 (one creature); your level + 6 vs. AC (Dragon 406)

"your level" in this case is your character's level. So when your warlock reaches L9, they get to summon their ally and it's to hit is X (whatever the constant there is) + 9. In the case of the Satyr of the night, their to-hit is 15 at L9 and increases every level.